# Check the selected values have same ids

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table named student which has fields [ID,NAME,EMAIL], Now I performed an operation as follows:

```
> $query =
> $this->db->select('*')->from('student')->where('EMAIL',xyz@gmail.com');
```

Now My requirement is that all the student IDS should be **same** for the above $query. How to do this thing ...

It exactly means I Need to **`check`** the query and If all the user Ids in the query are same the

[echo 'success' and also ID] else [echo 'false'];

```
ID  NAME         EMAIL 
1   alex      xyz@gmail.com
1   john      xyz@gmail.com
2   nithu     ooo@gmail.com
3   rohit     sda@gmail.com
4   jack      dad@gmail.com
```

Now on the above table if i perform above operation I will get tuple 1 and tuple 2..

So I need to check that both the tuples have same Id or not .In this case I have same id . so echo success and the ID which is 1 in this case or else echo false

Comment: Uh, what? Can you clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by `... the student IDS should be same...`. It's very unclear.

Comment: sir I may get many tuples and My requirement is that I need to check students Id's.. If all the student Ids are same then echo sucess and the student ID

Comment: did you mean you want to get all rows with a specific ID? something like `->from('student')->where('EMAIL','x@y.z')->where('ID',123)` ?

Comment: you can group by `student_id`, so that every distinct `student_id` with multiple entries in this table is in one row, and if there is more than one student with that email, they are all displayed. If you want only one student, use `LIMIT` or simply select students based on their `student_id`.

Comment: No sir I donno the ID here .. I need to check the query .. If all the IDs in the query are same the do the above procedure

Comment: Okay; I am officially confused. Can you add a few rows of sample data where the problem you are describing occures, and can you tell what data (= rows) you want to get in your query that you are currently (not) getting with your current query?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Sir i gave an example as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

I don't know codeigniter but I would do this logic:

```
SELECT count(*), student_id
FROM student
WHERE email = 'xyz@gmail.com'
GROUP BY student_id
```

If you get only ore row, it means that all student with email 'xyz@gmail.com' have the same id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_ids = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
  $all_ids[] = $row['id'];
}
$all_ids = array_unique($all_ids);
if (count($all_ids) == 1) {
  return array('success'=>true, 'id'=>$all_ids[0]);
} else {
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in CodeIgniter we do like this :-

```
$this->db->where('email', 'xyz@gmail.com');
$this->db->group_by("student_id"); 
$query = $this->db->get('student');
```

//when you don't select CodeIgniter  assume select all column